# How to implement such an application using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'd like to implement a sort of Addressbook/Contactbook using a Datagrid (or a List) and the MVVM pattern.

Something like in Outlook/Thunderbird, where you've a list of your contacts displayed with a 2-3 main fields (name surname for example), and when you double-click a contact, then you get a new modal box that displays all the details of this specific contact.

In fact my scenario is much more similar to an application that manages Customers, Orders and Products. The user would have as main view 3 datagrids showed through 3 tabs, one shows the list of Customers, one the Orders and one the Products.
Then in each view, you can Add (through opening an extra dialog), Delete (under certain conditions) an object.
Each object has a relation with another one.
For example, in a Customer instance, I've a list of Orders for that Customer and for each Order a list of Products ordered.

Since a couple of weeks/months, I'm reading a lot of stuff about MVVM pattern on the net, but somehow, I get confused. Until now, I could find any sample like this. (perhaps, I searched wrong?)

I'd like to implement something like this using the MVVM pattern.
How could I organize such an application?
Could someone help, how to structure it?
Is there a sample somewhere?

Thx in advance for your help.

Fred

Answer (score 2):

1) [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g53__vPihFY&feature=related) helped me with understanding the basics of MVVM.

2) Search on SO for "MVVM Master Detail".

3) "Delete (under certain conditions) an object": read about Commands and Relay Commands:

```
private RelayCommand _delete;
public ICommand Delete
{
    get
    {
        return _delete ?? (_delete = new RelayCommand(action => DoDelete(), condition => CanDelete));
    }
}

private bool CanDelete
{
    get { return true; // your condition }
}
```

4) "Then in each view, you can Add (through opening an extra dialog)"
    "Each object has a relation with another one" - you need to let other ViewModels know of changes. Typical solution is to use Mediator pattern. Please refer to following articles:

http://sachabarber.net/?p=477

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/03/20/more-than-just-mvc-for-wpf/

http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Edit: just found another nice and simple MVVM sample featuring sorting filtering and list navigation:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/

Answer (score 0):

[This article about Catel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Catel_part4.aspx) includes a "Person application". It is very simple, but allows you to manage a list of contacts. Maybe it's a starting point for you.

Comment: Hi, that sounds/looks good, at least it will inspire me I think. I'll study it deeper and see if I'll use your framework, or simply pick up some ideas! Thx!